# How do I open The Vault in Fociaugh Hollow?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In FFXV There is a cave You Enter called: Fociaugh Hollow, and Prompto gets taken by a Nagi. She asks you "Where is it?" We don't know, but we *Do* however find a vault. How do we open the vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The door you are asking about is apart of the series of side quests known as [Menace Beneath Lucis](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Menace_Beneath_Lucis). Unfortunately, base on the dialog you provided, you cannot open the door at this time.

This door cannot be unlock until you completed the following tasks:

1. Complete the story and reach the post game
2. Complete the dungeons: [Costlemark Tower](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Costlemark_Tower), [Crestholm Channels](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Crestholm_Channels), [Balouve Mines](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Balouve_Mines), and [Daurell Caverns](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Daurell_Caverns)

Once you met the required criteria, make your way over to the [Hunter's Headquarters](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Meldacio_Hunter_HQ') located southeast of the Vesperpool, and speak to Ezma. She will provide you the side quests and the Sealbreaker's Key to open the door(s).

Comment: So I have to do those in order, or are they royal tombs?

Comment: @RaineDrop953 You don't have to do them in that specific order. Two of them provide Royal Arms, the other two don't. As to why you have to complete those 4 specifically, I'm not sure. I know all 4 of those are optional dungeons, but there are other optional dungeons within the quest series that don't require completion

Comment: Where do I find the side quests?

Comment: I did it! I completed the quest. Thank you for your assistance! It helped a lot! I couldn't have done it without you!

Comment: @YouTubeRaineStorm I'm glad I was able to assist! :) Since it answered your question, feel free to accept the answer by click on the checkmark to the left of the answer

Comment: Guess who was able to beat them??? I did it Wonder Cricket!!! Although my YouTube channel cant upload PS4 videos. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @YouTube-RaineFall I personally don't have an answer for that. Comments aren't supposed to be used for discussion/questions, so feel free to submit a new question :)